# Multiple drop down validation

Tags: google-apps-script, dropdown

I am trying to make the below code available for all worksheet in Google sheet, but can not find a way: (I want to have multiplework sheet for May,june july and so on..)

```
var mainwsname = "APRIL 21";

var optionwsname = "DataBase1";

var firstlevelcoloumn = 4;
var secondlevelcoloumn = 5;

var thirdlevelcoloumn = 6;



var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainwsname);

var wsDatabase = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(optionwsname);

var options = wsDatabase.getRange(2,1,wsDatabase.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues();




function onEdit(activecell){
 var activecell = ws.getActiveCell();
 var val = activecell.getValue();
 var r = activecell.getRow();
 var c = activecell.getColumn();
 var wsName = activecell.getSheet().getName();

 if (wsName === mainwsname && c===firstlevelcoloumn && r>20){ 
    applyfirstlevelvalidation(val,r);
  } 
  else if(wsName === mainwsname && c===secondlevelcoloumn && r>20) {
      applysecondlevelvalidation(val,r);
  }



}// close onedit function

function applyfirstlevelvalidation(val,r){
  if(val === ""){
     ws.getRange(r,secondlevelcoloumn).clearContent();
     ws.getRange(r,secondlevelcoloumn).clearDataValidations();
   } else{
      ws.getRange(r,secondlevelcoloumn).clearContent();
      var filteredoptions = options.filter(function(o){return o[0]===val});
      var listtoapply = filteredoptions.map(function(o){return o[1]});
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,secondlevelcoloumn);
      applyvalidationtocell(listtoapply,cell);
   }
} 

function applysecondlevelvalidation(val,r){
  if(val === ""){
     ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcoloumn).clearContent();
     ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcoloumn).clearDataValidations();
   } else{
      ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcoloumn).clearContent();
      var firstlevelcolvalue = ws.getRange(r,firstlevelcoloumn).getValue();
      var filteredoptions = options.filter(function(o){return o[0]===firstlevelcolvalue && o[1]===val});
      var listtoapply = filteredoptions.map(function(o){return o[2]});
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcoloumn);
      applyvalidationtocell(listtoapply,cell);
   }
} 

function applysecondlevelvalidation(val,r){
  if(val == ""){

    ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcoloumn).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcoloumn).clearDataValidations();
  } else {
    ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcoloumn).clearContent();
    var firstLevelColValue = ws.getRange(r,firstlevelcoloumn).getValue();
    var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === firstLevelColValue && o[1] === val });
    var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[2]  });
    var cell = ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcoloumn);
    applyvalidationtocell(listToApply,cell);
  }
}



function applyvalidationtocell(list,cell) {
 
 
 var rule = SpreadsheetApp
 .newDataValidation()
 .requireValueInList(list)
 .setAllowInvalid(false)
 .build();


 cell.setDataValidation(rule);

}
```

I have declared the current sheet name as APRIL 21 as the Main worksheet variable. Please help me to declare multiple worksheets (such as MAY, JUNE, and so on). I may include a later month in the future.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide us with a demo spreadsheet with dummy values.

Comment: Hello PLease check below the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vyOpDS2Qgl5xJ_G1NfTfaayLLFCQfExjxsDQUuh1_1U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I checked on your sheet, but there's something that was not very clear on your workflow. Can you further explain how does the first, second, and third level column interact with the database sheet?

Comment: From sheet “DataBase1” I have Product, Category and Size, in sheet “APRIL 21” Header “Product” will have Data validation of “DataBase1” Products column, which will trigger “Category” only available for that option. Based on Product and Category cells, will open data validation of “Sizes”.I have opened the sheet if you need to check. This code works fine for the worksheet APRIL 21 only. Don’t know how to define multiple sheets in the same code. (For example: MAY 21, JUNE 21, JULY 21.. etc.)https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vyOpDS2Qgl5xJ_G1NfTfaayLLFCQfExjxsDQUuh1_1U/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var optionwsname = "DataBase1";
var firstlevelcoloumn = 4;
var secondlevelcoloumn = 5;
var thirdlevelcoloumn = 6;

var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var wsDatabase = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(optionwsname);
var options = wsDatabase.getRange(2,1,wsDatabase.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues();

function onEdit(activecell){
 var activecell = ws.getActiveCell();
 var val = activecell.getValue();
 var r = activecell.getRow();
 var c = activecell.getColumn();
 var wsName = activecell.getSheet().getName();

 if ( c===firstlevelcoloumn && r>20){ 
    applyfirstlevelvalidation(val,r);
  } 
  else if( c===secondlevelcoloumn && r>20) {
      applysecondlevelvalidation(val,r);
  }

}// close onedit function

function applyfirstlevelvalidation(val,r){
  if(val === ""){
     ws.getRange(r,secondlevelcoloumn).clearContent();
     ws.getRange(r,secondlevelcoloumn).clearDataValidations();
   } else{
      ws.getRange(r,secondlevelcoloumn).clearContent();
      var filteredoptions = options.filter(function(o){return o[0]===val});
      var listtoapply = filteredoptions.map(function(o){return o[1]});
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,secondlevelcoloumn);
      applyvalidationtocell(listtoapply,cell);
   }
} 

function applysecondlevelvalidation(val,r){
  if(val === ""){
     ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcoloumn).clearContent();
     ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcoloumn).clearDataValidations();
   } else{
      ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcoloumn).clearContent();
      var firstlevelcolvalue = ws.getRange(r,firstlevelcoloumn).getValue();
      var filteredoptions = options.filter(function(o){return o[0]===firstlevelcolvalue && o[1]===val});
      var listtoapply = filteredoptions.map(function(o){return o[2]});
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcoloumn);
      applyvalidationtocell(listtoapply,cell);
   }
} 

function applysecondlevelvalidation(val,r){
  if(val == ""){

    ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcoloumn).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcoloumn).clearDataValidations();
  } else {
    ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcoloumn).clearContent();
    var firstLevelColValue = ws.getRange(r,firstlevelcoloumn).getValue();
    var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === firstLevelColValue && o[1] === val });
    var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[2]  });
    var cell = ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcoloumn);
    applyvalidationtocell(listToApply,cell);
  }
}

function applyvalidationtocell(list,cell) {
 
 
 var rule = SpreadsheetApp
 .newDataValidation()
 .requireValueInList(list)
 .setAllowInvalid(false)
 .build();


 cell.setDataValidation(rule);

}
```

UPDATES:

1. Removed `var mainwsname = "APRIL 21";` and changed var `ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainwsname);` to `var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();` since `getActiveSheet();` reference the current sheet that you are working on so that the function runs on all sheets.
2. Removed `wsName === mainwsname` on your if-else statements since we won't be needing this condition anymore to run the script.

Comment: Awesome. It works perfectly.  Just to be sure, if I have another separate google sheet with the same tab name "Database1" will it pick up the code?

Comment: Yes that is correct. As long as it is a separate spreadsheet with the same tab name it should work fine. Also, if this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.